# java.io.IOException: Stream close. Problema con sockets en java

Tags: java, java-swing

Hola estoy realizando un programa en java swing mediante sockets que permita a usuarios registrados loguearse y visualizar en un JList la lista de clientes conectados y desconectados, lo que quiero es que cuando un cliente de cick en el JList pueda abrirse un chat con ese cliente.
Sin embargo estoy teniendo problemas con la comunicación de cliente a cliente, no logro capturar en el hilo la respuesta del servidor al cliente. Yo creo que estoy estructurando mal el código espero alguien pueda ayudarme y corregirme.

Clase de servidor

```
public static ArrayList<Client> listSessions = FileClients.getClients();
private static HashMap<String, ClientHandler> listSockets;

public initServer() {
    listSockets = new HashMap();
}

public void start() {
    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(ServerConfig.PORT)) {
        System.out.println("Servidor iniciado");
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientHandler clientHandler = new ClientHandler(socket);
            clientHandler.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.println("Error al iniciar el servidor");
    }
}

class ClientHandler extends Thread {

    private Socket socket;
    private DataInputStream in;
    private DataOutputStream out;
    private ObjectOutputStream outObject;

    public ClientHandler(Socket socket) {
        this.socket = socket;
    }

    public DataInputStream getIn() {
        return in;
    }

    public DataOutputStream getOut() {
        return out;
    }

    private void addClient(Client client) {
        listSessions.add(client);
    }

    private ArrayList<Client> getListSessions() {
        return listSessions;
    }

    private HashMap<String, ClientHandler> getListSockets() {
        return listSockets;
    }

    private void setClientMode(String userName, boolean mode) {
        Optional<Client> object = listSessions.stream()
                .filter(o -> o.getUserName().equals(userName))
                .map(o -> {
                    o.setMode(mode);
                    return o;
                })
                .findAny();
        int index = listSessions.indexOf(object.get());
        listSessions.set(index, object.get());
        if (mode) {
            listSockets.put(object.get().getUserName(), this);
        }
    }

    public void broadcastMessage(String sender, String dest, String message) {
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream send = new ObjectOutputStream(listSockets.get(dest).getOut());
            send.flush();
            send.writeUTF("SEND_MESSAGE");
            send.writeUTF(sender);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.toString());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

            while (true) {
                String command = in.readUTF();
                if (command.equals("SET_CLIENT")) {
                    ObjectInputStream inObject = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    Client client = (Client) inObject.readObject();
                    boolean resp = FileClients.setClient(client);
                    if (resp) {
                        addClient(client);
                    }
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeBoolean(resp);

                } else if (command.equals("CHECK_IS_CLIENT")) {
                    String userName = in.readUTF();
                    boolean isUser = FileClients.isClient(userName);
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeBoolean(isUser);

                } else if (command.equals("CHECK_SESSION")) {
                    String userName = in.readUTF();
                    String password = in.readUTF();
                    boolean login = FileClients.checkSessionClient(userName, password);
                    if (login) {
                        setClientMode(userName, true);
                        System.out.println("usuario logueado");
                    }
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeBoolean(login);
                    out.flush();
                    out.writeUTF("SET_LOG"); //aqui como prueba escribo este comando para verificar si el hilo de la clase ClientDAO lo detecta, sin embargo me da error de Stream close.

                } else if (command.equals("GET_LIST_SESSIONS")) {
                    ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeObject(getListSessions());

                } else if (command.equals("EXIT_SESSION")) {
                    String userName = in.readUTF();
                    //getListSockets().get(userName).close();
                    getListSockets().remove(userName);
                    setClientMode(userName, false);

                } else if (command.equals("SET_REQUEST")) {
                    String userNameSend = in.readUTF();
                    String userNameDest = in.readUTF();
                    broadcastMessage(userNameSend, userNameDest, "");
                    DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    out.writeBoolean(true);
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new initServer().start();
}
```

}

Clase cliente

public class ClientDAO {

```
public boolean setClient(Client client, String HOST, int PORT) {
    boolean status = false;
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
        DataOutputStream outData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outData.writeUTF("SET_CLIENT");
        ObjectOutputStream outObject = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outObject.writeObject(client);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        status = in.readBoolean();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return status;
}

public boolean isClient(String userName, String HOST, int PORT) {
    boolean status = false;
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("CHECK_IS_CLIENT");
        out.writeUTF(userName);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        status = in.readBoolean();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
    return status;
}

public boolean checkSessionClient(String userName, String password, String HOST, int PORT) {
    boolean status = false;
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("CHECK_SESSION");
        out.writeUTF(userName);
        out.writeUTF(password);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        status = in.readBoolean();
        Receiver receiver = new Receiver(in, socket.getInputStream()); //cada que un usuario entra al sistema, genero el hilo de cliente
        receiver.start();

        if (!status) {
            receiver.setRunning(false);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return status;
}

public ArrayList<Client> getListSessions(String HOST, int PORT) {
    ArrayList<Client> listSessions = new ArrayList();
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("GET_LIST_SESSIONS");
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        listSessions = (ArrayList<Client>) in.readObject();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return listSessions;
}

public void exitSession(String userName, String HOST, int PORT) {
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
        DataOutputStream outData = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        outData.writeUTF("EXIT_SESSION");
        outData.writeUTF(userName);
        outData.close();
        socket.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}

public boolean setRequest(String userNameSend, String userNameDest, String HOST, int PORT) {
    boolean status = false;
    try (Socket socket = new Socket(HOST, PORT)) {
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        out.writeUTF("SET_REQUEST");
        out.writeUTF(userNameSend);
        out.writeUTF(userNameDest);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        status = in.readBoolean();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
    return status;
}

static class Receiver extends Thread {

    private DataInputStream in;
    private InputStream inputStream;
    private boolean running = true;

    public Receiver(DataInputStream in, InputStream inputStream) {
        this.in = in;
        this.inputStream = inputStream;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean running) {
        this.running = running;
    }
    //aqui es donde quiero capturar esos comandos, pero obtengo un error de stream close
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (true) {
                if (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    String command = in.readUTF();
                    if (command.equals("SET_LOG")) {
                        System.out.println("Logueado");

                    } else if (command.equals("SEND_MESSAGE")) {
                        String user = in.readUTF();
                        System.out.println(user);
                    }
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Cabe destacar que todos los demás métodos me funcionan bien, puedo loguearme, ver la lista de clientes conectados y desconectados. El problema solo está en la parte del hilo del cliente, que ahí es donde quiero capturar las comunicaciones de cliente a cliente

Comment: Lo primero que te ayudará es que atrapes la excepción genérica [`Exception`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Exception.html) y revises el mensaje correspondiente.

Comment: Hola si lo he hecho y en el servidor me sale el error java.io.EOFException y en el cliente me sale stream close

Comment: ¿En cuál línea ocurre el error? Indícala en el código. Veo que para cada método pretendes usar un socket nuevo, debería ser el mismo para todos.

Comment: Hola puse unos comentarios en el código , el error se genera en el hilo de la clase del cliente. Y si pensé en eso de usar solo un socket, sin embargo todo lo demás me funciona bien, si ese fuera el problema no me funcionaría lo demás

Comment: Lo que sucede es que pierdes la secuencia de conversación. El cliente manda SET_CLIENT y espera por un boolean. EL servidor recibe SET_CLIENT y y al fin

Comment: Lo que sucede es que pierdes la secuencia de conversación. El cliente manda SET_CLIENT y espera por un boolean. EL servidor recibe SET_CLIENT y en envía el boolean que el cliente está esperando. Luego de esto tanto el server como el cliente quedan esperando, es decir, ninguno de los dos envía algo. Supuestamente el Cliente después recibir el boolean del servidor debería enviar al al server para que este responda, pero se queda en un loop hasta que que haya algo patra leer. Es decir, no estás siguiendo una secuencia de conversación cliente-servidor, servidor-cliente

Comment: A menos que en el Cliente te falte allgun tipo de iteracci9n con el usuario para recibir un comando y enviarlo al seever

Comment: Las otras funciones te funcionan porque es envio, repuesta y nada más. En el otro caso estas en un loop interminable donde no pides nada al server luego del SET_Client

Comment: Entiendo @JuanCarlosGuibovich, como puedo evitar perder la secuencia algún consejo?

Comment: El resumen el error son los ciclos infinitos, que al ya no haber lectura de nada se quedan esperando y genera el error, no?

Comment: En vez de System.err.println("Error al iniciar el servidor"); pon e.printStackTrace(System.err)